# referencing angularjs property value inside js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside view I have following snippet where I'm iterating trough collection of data

```
 <div class="tab-content" ng-controller="homeController as vm">
     <div class="tab-pane fade in active" ng-repeat="item in vm.data">
         {{item.Total}} 
         <script>
               var arrValues = [1, 5, 6, 7];
               // how can I access from here to item.Total                                    
         </script>
     </div>
</div>
```

I tried using following code to access `item.Total` but I'm getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined

```
if (arrValues.indexOf(item.Total) > -1) {
    console.log('A');
} else {
    console.log('B');
}
```

p.s. data binding works fine  `{{item.Total}}`  render value as expected.

Comment: This is really not angularish what is your main purpose?

Comment: you need to use $scope. Looks like plain js

Comment: @Jagen.. how do you mean it's not angularjs. I'm iterating inside view through collection of data exposed by angularjs controller. Main purpose is to access data inside js function which is displayed fine using data binding {{item.Total}}

Comment: *exposed by angularjs controller* - where is it exposed? Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

There are workarounds to achieve what you want, like using `angular.element(elementRef).scope().item`.

But this is not the recommended way to work with angular, you should manipulate the data in a controller or a service, not in the view.